# Tesseract image_to_string brings out the wrong numbers

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

Hi Im trying to create a program that takes a screenshot from another app, takes the numbers from said image and outputs it to txt and another window, my problem comes when the pytesseract.imagetostring brings another value other that the originial.

example:

Here the screenshot that my program took,[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dVmm.png),  ***the  number is 8258***

then I appplied a grayscale to help tesseract out, [image grayscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4S8L.png)

after that I aplied blur because aparentely this helps tesseract out, [image blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBk0J.png)

and finally I put a threshold because It helped to get the numbers correctly, [image thresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY4Jn.png)

after all of that is done I call pytessract to make a string form the image:

**data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')**

But my results are this for the txt, [tesseract txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScxSu.png) (its shows twice because I put 2 prints)

and for my window [image window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Yfo.png) , ***the value comes out as 68258***

I really don´t know why this is happening and Im all out of answers to fix it

im using tesseract v.5.0.0

this is the code Im using:

```
from ctypes import resize
import pygetwindow
import pyautogui
import cv2
import pytesseract
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from pygetwindow import PyGetWindowException
import numpy as np
import io

path = "C:\Image.png"

//this function takes the screnshot from the window of the other app
def getting_image():
   titles = pygetwindow.getAllTitles()
   window = pygetwindow.getWindowsWithTitle('Connect')[0]
   x1 = window.left
   y1 = window.top
   height = window.height
   width = window.width

   x2 = x1 + width
   y2 = y1 + height
   pyautogui.screenshot(path)


   im = Image.open(path)
   im = im.crop((x1+640,y1+125,x2-130,y2-670))
   im.save(path, dpi=(600,600))

//this function takes the image saved and convert it to text
def send_image():
   image = cv2.imread(path) //path is currently my C: drive, C:\Image.png 
      
   cv2.imshow('image_org',image)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   cv2.imshow('image_bckgray',gray)
   blur = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
   cv2.imshow('image_blur',blur)
   thresh = 255 - cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
   cv2.imshow('image_thresh',thresh)

   data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
   print(data)
   data = wording(data) //this just takes out the \x0c at the end of the file
   print(data)
   return (data)
```

Comment: better create `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: what do you use to load image? For example `cv2` uses color `BGR` instead of `RGB`. You could also use `for`-loop to test code with different values `psm` and `oem` - maybe other values will give better result.

Comment: your first image has window title bar with text - if you use this image to get text then window title can make problem. Better show real image (use `save()`) instead of screenshots.

Comment: I used your first image (without `grayscale`, `blur`, `thresh`) and I got `8958<enter>`, And when I croped it - to remove window title - then I get `8258` (Tesseract 4.1.1)

Comment: I got the same results (`8958<enter>` and `8258`) with Tesseract 5.0.0-rc1-24-g44690 (Python 3.8 ,Linux Mint 20)